# What are Time Capsules in Julian Barbour's theory of a Timeless Universe?

Tags: time, causality

Barbour (The End of Time, The Janus Point) describes Time Capsules as Nows (instants of the universe) with awareness of other instants. That we experience time because we 'live in a Time Capsule'. I am not sure I understand this concept.

Within this framework, does Causality exist without these Time Capsules? (yes or no question format to meet requirements of this forum).

Anyways, hoping someone can provide a simple explanation of Time Capsules, as I find the whole concept of a timeless universe very intriguing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In 2011, I talk to Dr. Barbour himself, via e-mail, and this was what he told me about his Time Capsule concept:

"Let me give one example that might help: Where do the integers (natural numbers 1,2,3,...) come from? They all somehow exist together; the most that one can say is that they satisfy timeless rules. Now each integer has a unique decomposition into prime numbers, e.g., 6=2x3. There is a sense in which 6 contains both 2 and 3. In this way, a present Now (if highly structured) can contain (to some extent) a different thing."